# WP7: How to open file in my app from the browser or mail client?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to register a file extension specifically to my app so that I can download and open it from the mail app or the browser?

Adobes Pdf-Reader can do this so I suppose it is possible but maybe there is special plumbing involved we have no access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular 3rd party application, you can't. There's a trick, using the [Web Browser Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394020%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for the purpose.

But it'll only work for file-extensions known to the system.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, that is a feature not available to the general developers, as I'd bet Adobe Reader uses some sort of Interop to achieve that (and Interop is NOT open to developers)...